# Jenkins delete my old builds

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins server delete old builds and I can't look history of builds. On configure job: old builds must be available. I don't know what happened.

But on server have jobs, where biulds doesn't deleted and configures are the same.

Please, help me.

Jenkins: ver. 1.492

Config:
[image]

Comment: obvious question, but what values have you got in the job config fields "*Days to keep builds*" and "*Max # of builds to keep*" ?

Comment: hmm... the only thing I can suggest is try updating to the latest Jenkins version. I note in [the changelog](https://jenkins-ci.org/changelog) that there's been a couple of entries in recent version about builds disappearing from the build history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I upgraded Jenkins server(1.508), and all builds now stay.
Thanks!!!